# http:// in a text field crashes to 404 error - html

Tags: html, http, http-status-code-404

"http://" crashes 1st field

Not http or http:, or http://

```
<form action="samepage.php" method="post">
   username:<br>
   <input type="text" name="username" value="" />       
   field2:<br>
   <input type="text" name="field2" value="" />
   <input type="submit" value="Register" />
</form>
```

This is pretty much the exact code...if I put http:// into the username field I receive error.

" 
You don't have permission to access /samepage.php on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."

If I put it in the second field I receive no error.

I am stumped.

---

```
IndexIgnore .htaccess */.??* *~ *# */HEADER* */README* */_vti*

AuthName *****.com
AuthType Basic 
AuthUserFile /home/*****/.htpasswds/.htpasswd
Options -Indexes
<Files private.php>
require valid-user
</Files>
```

---

So yeah let's get rid of all the nonsense. This fails http:// in first slot, works in second.
There is no php or mysql there was originally I've done every debugging I can think of.

```
<form action="newEmptyPHP.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username" value="" />
    <input type="text" name="twitter" value="" />
    <input type="submit" value="Register" /> 
</form>
```

---

I have contacted my host security team hopefully they can figure this out. It has to be a setting unless there is somewhere posted that the first text field in any form can't have http:// in it.

---

New information the host is using modsecurity.org if that helps.

Comment: Why would you ever need a url as a username? ;)

Comment: Post your `.htaccess` file code.

Comment: It's happening in multiple files, the one I noticed it on the first entry is a "url slot to the person's twitter account" so the http:// fails it. Htaccess posted

Comment: Well sir, you have a buhhhg. Note that the form is sent as POST so forget about it somehow choosing a different resource path (which is what .htaccess can look at) - the actual resource path used can be verified looking at the access logs or using a tool like Firebug/Fiddler2 (but it won't change; it will always be "samepage2.php"). This leaves the probable issue coming from incorrect usage of the data within the handling application (i.e. PHP code) itself.

Comment: I have spent a few hours on this it's a large project and I ended up separating it down to this most basic thing........I literally have a file with the above sitting in it. That single form causes the error every time.

Comment: Sounds like server security gone insane.

Comment: Server is using modsecurity.org

Answer (score 0):

Unbelievable - it is common security practice to ban a list of keywords people may use as inputs for important fields.

Username,email, name, and a lot of others all will receive instant warnings from the server. This is pre-code processing.

To make the above code not give me an error I simply cannot use any string that contains username for my username input on my form.

Thanks for looking if you tried.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem.  To avoid storing "http://" and "https://" in any of the fields, you can store the protocol without slashes in option tags.  The domain name goes in the text input.

```
<form action="page.php" method="post">
    <select name="theprotocol">
        <option value="http">http://</option>
        <option value="https">https://</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="thedomain" value="" /> 
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
</form>
```